# How can I stop accidentally deleting header images while highlighting text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I have a Word 2010 template which includes a company logo as part of the header. The logo is positioned relative to the page and has *Text Wrapping* set to *In Front of Text*.

[image: Header with company logo]

**Unfortunately, highlighting the title text also highlights any images in the header...**

[image: Header with highlighted text and logo]

**...which makes it easy to accidentally erase the company logo.**

[image: The header is empty now. Whoops.]

The company logo should be constant for each document, and should not be modified when highlighting header text.

---

### Is there a way to prevent the company logo from being highlighted with the header text? Alternatively, is there a way to 'lock' or 'anchor' the company logo in place so it cannot be accidentally modified?

<sub>*Note: If possible, I would prefer to avoid using macros for security reasons.*</sub>

Comment: What if you disable text wrapping and set the image to an arbitrary position and move it there? Its not like the image needs to be moved with the text given its in a header, right?

Comment: Why not move the image so that it's anchored in the footer instead (but still appears in its current position)?

Comment: @cnread That's a clever solution which worked perfectly! Post it as an answer and I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the image so that it's anchored in the footer instead, but still appears in its current position.

1. Right-click the image, click **Size and Position**, and then, on the **Position** tab, make a note of the various settings.
2. Cut the image out of the header, and paste it into the footer.
3. Adjust the positioning settings so that the image appears in its former location at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a "Picture content control" object rather than an inserted image.

You'll need to have [enabled the developer tab for the ribbon](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45) first.

Then, in the `controls` group of the Developers tab there is an "image" icon which is the Picture content control object.

[image: Developer tools - Picture content control icon]

Select that and it will insert an image box. Click the image icon in the box to choose an image.

Once you have the image in place you can select it and then click "Properties" in the controls group of the developer tab. A window will pop up with two options:

- Content control cannot be deleted
- Contents cannot be edited

Check them as required and you will no longer be able to delete the image.

---

Just to note, while the image control is editable you should be able to do most of the same formatting tricks as a normal inserted image, including wrapping text around it or putting it behind text.

It also seems that you can insert an image, select it and then press the button for the image control object icon and it will automatically wrap it around the selected image, but that doesn't seem to work in headers, at least it doesn't in my Word 2007.

Comment: It seems 'Picture content control' objects have their text wrapping locked to "in line with text". Changing the image wrapping disables the "properties" button

Comment: So it does. That is... *odd*.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro  Sorry for the edit trampling. Seems that this way has some quirks, you might be able to deal with the formatting using a table, but again deleting the table will kill the image. Seems no way is without its pitfalls.

Comment: Strangely enough, this method seems to have fixed my issue. My document has two header images. After making the top-left image a Picture Control object, ***both*** images were no longer highlighted with text, even after changing the image wrapping. Both images can still be manually selected as the properties weren't altered, but they aren't highlighted with text anymore.

Comment: Seems like using the controls has that as a neat side effect meaning that the delete protection isn't needed then.  I'll see about making this a two part answer with caveats later tonight hopefully, first part would be to use the controls as it takes it out of the flow of text and thus solving the problem, and then if that's not enough using the protection to actively prevent their deletion. I like the solution of putting the image in the footer but moving its placement into the header area, neat way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried holding down CTRL and left clicking on the image to 'deselect' it when everything is highlighted?

Comment: Preferably I'd like to prevent the images from being highlighted at all, since others will be using this template. However, this is a very good workaround for personal use!

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is,  if you highlight too far then don't hit delete. If you highlight too far, highlight less. You can use the shift and left arrow to highlight less far.  And Check what you highlighted before you hit delete.

I think it might happen if the mouse moves down too far. You only want to highiight one sentence so you can experiment with shift and ctrl and arrows. e.g. shift ctrl right arrow..  Highlighting what you want and not more.  Or you can do shift down which might highlight the image too but then do shift left arrow to highlight back to just up till the end of that title. (of course, shift+A,shift+B is same as shift+A,B.

If I have a load of text to highlight in word i'l often highlight up almost all the lines with a drag of the mouse then i'll drag up so it doesn't go too far highlightimg inages. And i'll use shift+arrow+ctrl, to highlight less so it just highlights all the lines and not any image.  In your case with just 6 words to highlight  and they span over two lines. .I wouldn't use the mouse. I'd use shift ctrl forward arrow. With a shift ctrl  back arrow if i went too far.